# Plot histogram from unbinned file in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a json file data (2Go) where each line is (threadTitle, numberOfSubscribers)

```
thread1 1092
thread2 44481
thread3 12105
thread4 2835
thread5 4292
...
```

I want to plot an histogram in python with :

Y : number of threads

X : 5 ranges of # of subscribers. [0 to 100], [101 to 1000], [1001 to 5000], [5001 to 10000] and [10001 and more]

Is there a way to do it efficiently with any library in python?

Currently, I have to preprocess the data this way and then plot the data, but that seems a bit cumbersome.

```
subreddit_subscriber = open("subreddit_subscriber.txt","w");

# 5 counters, one for each bin
subreddit_count = dict();
subreddit_count["below_100"] = 0;
subreddit_count["below_1000"] = 0;
subreddit_count["below_5000"]= 0;
subreddit_count["below_10000"] = 0;
subreddit_count["more_10000"] = 0;
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        subreddits = json.loads(line);
        subscribers = subreddits["subscribers"]
        #increment the counter according to the number of subscribers
        if(subscribers <=100):
            subreddit_count["below_100"] += 1;
        elif (subscribers <= 1000):
            subreddit_count["below_1000"] += 1;
        elif (subscribers <= 5000):
            subreddit_count["below_5000"] += 1;
        elif (subscribers <= 10000):
            subreddit_count["below_10000"] += 1;
        else:
            subreddit_count["more_10000"] += 1;

for key in subreddit_count.keys():
    subreddit_subscriber.write(key + "\t" + str(subreddit_count[key]));
subreddit_subscriber.close();
```

** First line of the original dataset is this one: **

```
{"header_img":"...","submit_link_label":"Submit a new post","name":"t5_2qgzg","description":"/r/business brings you the best of your business section. From tips for running a business, to pitfalls to avoid, /r/business teaches you the smart moves and helps you dodge the foolish.\n\n/r/business is not the place for stories about the government's economic policies or corporate corruption. \n#### Rules:\n\n1. **This is not the place to promote your business.**  \nAny and every post promoting a business in any capacity will be removed.  \n  \n6. **Spamming will result in an instant ban.**  \nNo mercy for spammers.   \n  \n2. By posting here, __you agree that you have no connections to the site of the articles you submit__, If you do, we will instantly ban you.   \n\n2. We do not allow __['blogspam'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blogspam)__, any post that looks like blogspam will be removed.\n\n2. Political submission are not allowed and will be removed. Use /r/politics.\n\n3. Examples of Corporations behaving badly? That goes in /r/greed.  \n\n4. This place should have a \"business casual\" feel. Like you're at a networking party...**make jokes, not offensive comments.**  \n\n5. Please follow [Reddiquette.](http://www.reddit.com/wiki/reddiquette)\n\n6. If you link directly to video content you need to leave a comment, or state\nclearly in the title, what the video is about\n\n*Helpful Subreddits:*\n\n* /r/Accounting\n\n* /r/Banking\n\n* /r/BusinessHub\n\n* /r/BusinessInsiders\n\n* /r/BusinessSchool\n\n* /r/Consulting\n\n* /r/Corruption\n\n* /r/Economics\n\n* /r/Economy\n\n* /r/Finance\n\n* /r/InternationalBusiness\n\n* /r/Investing\n\n* /r/InvestmentClub\n\n* /r/MBA\n\n* /r/RealEstate\n\n* /r/Sales\n\n\n\n*Supply chain and logistics:*\n\n* /r/mailroom\n\n*Small Businesses:*\n\n* /r/Entrepreneur \n\n* /r/SmallBusiness \n\n* /r/StartUps \n  \n  \n^[Photography](http://www.flickr.com/photos/reactionphotography) ^of ^the ^header ^licensed ^under ^[CC](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/deed.en)","suggested_comment_sort":null,**"subscribers":201926**,"header_title":"/r/business brings you the best of your business section.","header_size":[1,1],"public_traffic":false,"description_html":"&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/business\"&gt;/r/business&lt;/a&gt; brings you the best of your business section. From tips for running a business, to pitfalls to avoid, &lt;a href=\"/r/business\"&gt;/r/business&lt;/a&gt; teaches you the smart moves and helps you dodge the foolish.&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/business\"&gt;/r/business&lt;/a&gt; is not the place for stories about the government&amp;#39;s economic policies or corporate corruption. &lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;h4&gt;Rules:&lt;/h4&gt;\n\n&lt;ol&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This is not the place to promote your business.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br/&gt;\nAny and every post promoting a business in any capacity will be removed.  &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Spamming will result in an instant ban.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br/&gt;\nNo mercy for spammers.   &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;By posting here, &lt;strong&gt;you agree that you have no connections to the site of the articles you submit&lt;/strong&gt;, If you do, we will instantly ban you.   &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;We do not allow &lt;strong&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blogspam\"&gt;&amp;#39;blogspam&amp;#39;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;, any post that looks like blogspam will be removed.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Political submission are not allowed and will be removed. Use &lt;a href=\"/r/politics\"&gt;/r/politics&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Examples of Corporations behaving badly? That goes in &lt;a href=\"/r/greed\"&gt;/r/greed&lt;/a&gt;.  &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;This place should have a &amp;quot;business casual&amp;quot; feel. Like you&amp;#39;re at a networking party...&lt;strong&gt;make jokes, not offensive comments.&lt;/strong&gt;  &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Please follow &lt;a href=\"http://www.reddit.com/wiki/reddiquette\"&gt;Reddiquette.&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;If you link directly to video content you need to leave a comment, or state\nclearly in the title, what the video is about&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;/ol&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Helpful Subreddits:&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;ul&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Accounting\"&gt;/r/Accounting&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Banking\"&gt;/r/Banking&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/BusinessHub\"&gt;/r/BusinessHub&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/BusinessInsiders\"&gt;/r/BusinessInsiders&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/BusinessSchool\"&gt;/r/BusinessSchool&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Consulting\"&gt;/r/Consulting&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Corruption\"&gt;/r/Corruption&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Economics\"&gt;/r/Economics&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Economy\"&gt;/r/Economy&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Finance\"&gt;/r/Finance&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/InternationalBusiness\"&gt;/r/InternationalBusiness&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Investing\"&gt;/r/Investing&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/InvestmentClub\"&gt;/r/InvestmentClub&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/MBA\"&gt;/r/MBA&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/RealEstate\"&gt;/r/RealEstate&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Sales\"&gt;/r/Sales&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;/ul&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Supply chain and logistics:&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;ul&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/mailroom\"&gt;/r/mailroom&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;/ul&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Small Businesses:&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;ul&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/Entrepreneur\"&gt;/r/Entrepreneur&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/SmallBusiness\"&gt;/r/SmallBusiness&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/StartUps\"&gt;/r/StartUps&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;/ul&gt;\n\n&lt;p&gt;&lt;sup&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/reactionphotography\"&gt;Photography&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/sup&gt; &lt;sup&gt;of&lt;/sup&gt; &lt;sup&gt;the&lt;/sup&gt; &lt;sup&gt;header&lt;/sup&gt; &lt;sup&gt;licensed&lt;/sup&gt; &lt;sup&gt;under&lt;/sup&gt; &lt;sup&gt;&lt;a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/deed.en\"&gt;CC&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/sup&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;","hide_ads":false,"icon_img":"","public_description":"/r/business brings you the best of your business section. From tips for running a business, to pitfalls to avoid, /r/business teaches you the smart moves and helps you dodge the foolish.","created_utc":1190054517,"submit_text":"Please remember our sub rules:\n\n1. This is not the place to promote\nyour business.\nAny and every post promoting a\nbusiness in any capacity will be\nremoved.\n\n\n2. Spamming will result in an instant\nban.\nNo mercy for spammers.\n\n\n3. By posting here, you agree that you\nhave no connections to the site of\nthe articles you submit, If you do,\nwe will instantly ban you.\n\n\n4. We do not allow 'blogspam' , any\npost that looks like blogspam will be\nremoved.\n\n\n5. Political submission are not allowed\nand will be removed. Use /r/politics .\n\n\n6. Examples of Corporations behaving\nbadly? That goes in /r/greed .\n\n\n7. This place should have a \"business\ncasual\" feel. Like you're at a\nnetworking party... make jokes, not\noffensive comments.\n\n\n8. Please follow Reddiquette.","title":"business","subreddit_type":"public","url":"/r/business/","wiki_enabled":false,"submission_type":"any","public_description_html":"&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=\"/r/business\"&gt;/r/business&lt;/a&gt; brings you the best of your business section. From tips for running a business, to pitfalls to avoid, &lt;a href=\"/r/business\"&gt;/r/business&lt;/a&gt; teaches you the smart moves and helps you dodge the foolish.&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;","banner_size":null,"accounts_active":null,"lang":"en","key_color":"","id":"2qgzg","icon_size":null,"submit_text_label":null,"submit_text_html":"&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Please remember our sub rules:&lt;/p&gt;\n\n&lt;ol&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is not the place to promote\nyour business.\nAny and every post promoting a\nbusiness in any capacity will be\nremoved.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Spamming will result in an instant\nban.\nNo mercy for spammers.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;By posting here, you agree that you\nhave no connections to the site of\nthe articles you submit, If you do,\nwe will instantly ban you.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;We do not allow &amp;#39;blogspam&amp;#39; , any\npost that looks like blogspam will be\nremoved.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Political submission are not allowed\nand will be removed. Use &lt;a href=\"/r/politics\"&gt;/r/politics&lt;/a&gt; .&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Examples of Corporations behaving\nbadly? That goes in &lt;a href=\"/r/greed\"&gt;/r/greed&lt;/a&gt; .&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;This place should have a &amp;quot;business\ncasual&amp;quot; feel. Like you&amp;#39;re at a\nnetworking party... make jokes, not\noffensive comments.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Please follow Reddiquette.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\n&lt;/ol&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;","comment_score_hide_mins":0,"quarantine":false,**"display_name":"business"**,"collapse_deleted_comments":false,"banner_img":"","over18":false}
```

**EDIT: ** [After plotting Jezrael's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIvSQ.png)

Comment: What is structure of `json` data?

Comment: A simple one (no array, no nesting)
{title, subscribers, other data...}

Comment: So `df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)` working nice? Or need `df = pd.read_json(file)` ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that my file was 2Go. When I executed the first line (pd.read_json), the python console froze. I'm looking if there is a way to stream read it.

Comment: Can you add to question first 3 rows from file?

Comment: I can't add 3 lines because of SO's policy. But they are pretty much the same.

Comment: Thank you, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can read only value `subscribers` to list, then create `Series` and use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for binning, [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for count and last [`plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
L = []
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        L.append(json.loads(line)["subscribers"])
print (L)

s = pd.Series(L)
#print (s)


l = ['below_100','below_1000','below_5000','below_10000','more_10000']
a = pd.cut(s, bins=[-1,100,1000,5000,10000,np.inf], labels=l).value_counts()
#print (a)


a.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, I wasn't able to compute your code earlier.
The result didn't plot an histogram but a straight decreasing line, with y-axis the number of subreddits and x-axis without any labels. I have added the plot in my first post.

Comment: @NoSmile - You need `a.plot.bar()` instaed `a.plot()`, so sorry.

Comment: I've also tried .plot().bar() and it gave me this result :

   dp, x, height, width, y, kwargs = matcher(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'height'

Comment: There is typo, not `a.plot().bar()` but `a.plot.bar()`, omit first `()`